# Creating warning for hotkey use in certain programmes

Tags: autohotkey

Trying to have a popup warning on hotkey activation on specifically slack.

The Ideal result is:

I enter my hotkey,
AHK checks if active window is slack.exe
If yes, creates a warning dialogue with a Yes/No prompt, allowing me to abort

If the active window is not slack, the hotkey proceeds.

I know I could go and add the #IfWinActive tag to everything, or just flat bar them from working in slack, but I'd like the ability to choose.

Appreciate any help!

I've figured out parts of this, such as
`#IfWinActive ahk_exe slack.exe` to identify slack, and I've figured out the IfMsgBox Yes/No portion, I just can't seem to find a tag for any hotkey activation, typically I use intext ones (enter `?fault` to spew out a basic fault acknowledgement template)

Comment: How do you type and activate the hotkey in slack?

Comment: Usually by having the wrong window focused - Typically I'm using this to speed up call templates.
?id will spit out a basic ID template for me.

Comment: You can also use Hotstings instead of Hotkeys.